# wordpress wp_mail() function cannot receive attachment when using syntax $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]

Tags: wordpress, file, attachment

```
//1st:   
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']));
$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/".$_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);

//2nd
$attachment = array($_FILES['upload_file'][tmp_name]);

//wp_mail function:
if ( wp_mail( $to_email, $email_subject, $email_body, $header, $attachment) ) {
            _e("Message Sent Successfully!", 'framework');
        } else {
            _e("Server Error: WordPress mail method failed!", 'framework');
        }
```

The file I want to send is named as "xxx.pdf"

For the 1st code, I can upload my file to my server, with the same name as the original file, but the email I received does not contain any attachment.

For the 2nd code, I receive the attachment but without any specified format (e.g. phpUOtAZU). However, when I add the file extension (e.g. phpUOtAZU.pdf), it will have the same content as the file that I want to be sent.

How can I receive a email with the original file as the attachment (e.g. xxx.pdf)? If more code's information is needed, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in #1 you have `$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']` but then `$_FILES['attachment']['name']` - referencing a different file input ('attachment' rather than 'upload_file'). Couldn't be that could it?

You've also missed off the basename() function when defining $attachments. So does this work?

```
$attachment = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['upload_file']['name']));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $attachment);

if ( wp_mail( $to_email, $email_subject, $email_body, $header, array($attachment)) ) {
    _e("Message Sent Successfully!", 'framework');
} else {
    _e("Server Error: WordPress mail method failed!", 'framework');
}
```

This works for me, I'm doing almost exactly the same thing.

If you're writing a plugin I think good WordPress etiquette would be to have your own folder within /upload/ which you could create on plugin activation and remove on deactivation.